# How do I rotate 2 steppers at the same time?

Tags: arduino

Is there somethimg like theading in arduino?

I'm using Stepper.h library to use steppers and I want to rotate two of them at the same time, is that possible?

Additional info:

I'm using two drivers ULN2003 and Arduino Nano to controll steppers.

Code for one of them:

```
  void AStep(){
        AStepper.step(i1.toInt());
        display.println("Turned A stepper;");
        display.display();
  }
```

Comment: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/286/how-can-i-create-multiple-running-threads

Answer (score 1):

You can make them appeir as they are moving at the some time by making the stepper do smaller "steps".

The only thing is that this method **DOESN'T** make them turn in *actual* sync.

[Snippet by PaulS from the Arduino forums.](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=93706.0%5C)

```
for(int s=0; s<step_360; s++)
{
 AStepper.step(1);
 BStepper.step(1);
}
```